# FullCalendar Saving issue

Tags: fullcalendar

I am having trouble getting my FullCalendar to save any information if I hit save.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[www.synergyrecycling-calendar.com/calendar-admin.html](http://www.synergyrecycling-calendar.com/calendar-admin.html)

Code for the buttons

```
buttons: { 
  save : function() { 
   calEvent.id = id; id++; 
   calEvent.start = new Date(startField.val());
   calEvent.end = new Date(endField.val()); 
   calEvent.title = titleField.val(); 
   calEvent.prototype = eventField.val();
   calEvent.body = bodyField.val(); 
   $calendar.fullCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent); 
   $dialogContent.dialog("close"); 
   }
}
```

I found the problem, but I am not sure how to fix it.

```
<select name="start">
  <option value="">Select Start Time</option>
  <option value="08:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)">08:00 am</option>
  <option value="Sun May 22 2011 08:15:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)">08:15 am</option>
  <option value="Sun May 22 2011 08:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)">08:30 am</option>
```

Comment: I assume clicking `add event` and then filling the form in is supposed to add an event.. i press the button and nothing happens.. where do you seem to the problem.. submitting the info? or ...

Comment: ok never mind- i pressed on the day and a nice popup came p up and pressed saved.. what actually happens behing the save button? The save button does not seem to post anything?

Comment: buttons: {
save : function() {
calEvent.id = id;
id++;
calEvent.start = new Date(startField.val());
calEvent.end = new Date(endField.val());
calEvent.title = titleField.val();
calEvent.prototype = eventField.val();
calEvent.body = bodyField.val();
$calendar.fullCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
$dialogContent.dialog("close");
},

Comment: I found the problem, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Problem coding-
<select name="start"><option value="">Select Start Time</option><option value="08:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)">08:00 am</option><option value="Sun May 22 2011 08:15:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)">08:15 am</option><option value="Sun May 22 2011 08:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)">08:30 am</option>

if it has the date in the option it will work, but I need to just select time not the date because the date is already formatted do to the day.click

Comment: So you need to get the time in the text's format? like the part `08:15 am` and where exactly do you want it to go? into the cal.event?

Comment: Man you have some spaghetti code there.. i am trying to check your site source and it looks like .. err... you need to put all that in separate .js and functions.. but it works i suppose.. its just difficult to debug.

Comment: Sorry mate i started to look at your code.. but its just a massive thing to understand wahts happening there.. .i tried something here http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/pYGBm/  but .. yea

Comment: ppumkin, I didn't write that segment of code, I found it and was trying to edit it.  Hints why im having trouble lol, but I thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Maybe youll get it work yourself but in the meant time i will look at it from time to time to try and figure it out - it must be a simple thing

Comment: Will do, I will keep you posted on any updates.  Thanks for the help pumkin.